# mysql process doesn't have a process id

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, process, digital-ocean

I have a mysql instance running on digitalocean cloud.
sometimes the mysql instance get crash after working for few days,so i am monitoring that using monit to restart as soon as it crashes.

[image]

Today i came across this situation,it shows that the mysql is still running but it doesn't have a process id (i think because of which i couldn't access the mysql database and after restating it was working fine).can anybody tell why this situation has occured...?

Comment: "but it doesn't have a process id " --- what does it mean?

Comment: as u can see after restarting the mysql the process no. 25185 is associated with the mysql instance...it was not there before

Comment: It seems your understanding is practically wrong. While stopping mysql, it wont display the Process ID , and while starting up  it displays. If you want to display PID during mysql start up too, edit /etc/init.d/mysql script accordingly. Below comments by sadhikasan, will do good for identify currently running process.

Comment: @ganeshragav ...i am not asking about why it is not showing pid when it is stopped,the  question i asked is when i give this command "service mysql status",it shows the mysql is start/running,if it is running then i want it's pid to be shown.

Comment: Ok then crash, corruption of db might be the case. Have you checked /var/log/mysql.log for error messages during this time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Monit` will always check that the pid number in a pid file belongs to a running process. If a program crashes and dies in a "normal" manner, then the process ID (pid) will not exist and monit will know that the program is not running and restart it even if a pid file exist. Some serverscancrash and leave a zombie process, and appear to run. Monit also test for zombie processes and will raise an alert if a process has become a zombie.

This may be due to an error in `monit` that prevent it from remove monitoring *zombie* process. So try modify your configuration

> check process mysql with pidfile /opt/mysql/data/myserver.mydomain.pid
>      group database
>      start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
>      stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
>      if failed host  192.168.1.1 port 3306 protocol mysql then restart
>      if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
>      depends on mysql_bin
>      depends on mysql_rc
>    check file mysql_bin with path /opt/mysql/bin/mysqld
>      group database

More details [here](http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples#mysqld)

Answer (score 2):

There are several option you may check your mysql process_id

```
 1st. $ ps aux | grep mysql
```

This will show something like below with [**Reference**](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-display-process-pid-under-linux-unix/)

```
mysql    28290  1.1  2.7 340496 56812 ?        Sl   Jul31 348:27 /usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --skip-locking --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

         ^^^^
      process_id
```

Second  Option to check process id of mysql [**Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html).

```
2nd. mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 534
   User: root
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: NULL
   Info: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In above example it displays Id of threads are running. Above example It is `534`.

Third Option to check process id of mysql [**Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html).

```
3rd. $ pidof mysqld
```

Fourth Option to check process id of mysql [**Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)

```
4th. mysql> SELECT CONNECTION_ID();
        -> 23786
```

Answer (score 1):

Every process has to have a process id. In order to find out what pid does your mysql instance have, you can use the following command in the terminal:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

This should show something like this:

```
_mysql           3034   0,0  0,3  2664388  58460   ??  S    Mer01pm   4:00.97 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld ....
```

The second element in the list (in my case 3034) is the process id.

Answer (score 0):

It can be for various reasons. To identify the problem you need to look at the logs. However it seems like a bug to me. What version of mysql are you using and can you update it ?

Thanks

Comment: version: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log

Comment: Did you find anything in the logs ? Also can you update your mysql server version

Answer (score 0):

You can access process Id like below:
login to Mysql as admin:

```
 mysql -uroot -ppassword;
```

And than run command:

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

You will get something like below :

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User        | Host               | db       | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 49 | application | 192.168.44.1:51718 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |  183 |       | NULL             ||
| 55 | application | 192.168.44.1:51769 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |  148 |       | NULL             |
| 56 | application | 192.168.44.1:51770 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |  148 |       | NULL             |
| 57 | application | 192.168.44.1:51771 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |  148 |       | NULL             |
| 58 | application | 192.168.44.1:51968 | XXXXXXXX | Sleep   |   11 |       | NULL             |
| 59 | root        | localhost          | NULL     | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+----+-------------+--------------------+----------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

You will see complete details of different connections. Now you can kill the sleeping connection as below: